# onclick с php или js без ajax

Tags: php, javascript, веб-программирование

Пытаюсь выполнить запрос п онажатию на клавишу но столкнулся с проблемой из-за того что php функция не вызывается в onclick. Чем можно заменить? к сожалению js и ajax не знаю(

```
<html>
<input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search.." value="<=$varsearch?>">
 <button onclick="Search()">Find</button>

<?php function Search()
{
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM `sandoz` WHERE MATCH ($data) AGAINST ('%$varsearch%')";
}
?>
</html>
```

Comment: http://phpfaq.ru/newbie/na_tanke#js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP Обрабатывается на стороне сервера, а JS на клиентской. Поэтому так сделать не выйдет

Можно передать параметры через форму, если ajax не знаете

index.html

```
<html>
 <form method="post" action="handler.php">
  <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search..">
  <input type="submit">
 </form>
</html>
```

handler.php

```
<?php
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM `sandoz` WHERE MATCH ($data) AGAINST ('". $_POST["search"] ."')";
```

Comment: это с использованием $GET, $POST?

Comment: @Elanyl Привел пример с использованием POST, аналогично можно использовать GET

Comment: в общем можно описывать в других файлах куски кода и вызывать как функцию или процедуру? я просто с++ только знаю так чтобы писать, первый раз веб делаю))

Comment: @Elanyl Посмотрите документацию на http://php.net. В PHP можно использовать как структурный подход так и ООП